# What is advantage, of using IS4 login screen?

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, identity

I'm wondering why we have to redirect to login page to Identity provider, why we cant just sent our data from our own build login screen?

What gives us this redirect and literally typing login and password on IP login page?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have many clients (mean client applications) then user must login just once at your IP page, next time user will obtain authentication without any login-password promts;
2. Additional layer of security via right defined `redirect_urls`;
3. If you use [`PKCE`](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce), then again additional layer of security, you can prevent `CSRF` and `authorization code` injection attacks.

This is the main advantages for me.